# Total variation $t\mapsto \|f\|_{t,\operatorname{var}}$ of a cadlag function $f$ with finite variation is cadlag

Tags: probability, probability-theory, continuity, total-variation

If $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ is cadlag and has finite variation, is it true that the total variation $t\mapsto \operatorname{Var}(X)_t$ is cadlag? ($\operatorname{Var}$ denotes the total variation)

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168673/total-variation-of-a-cadlag-function) question is related. Erik has seen the proof concerning right-continuity. I *want* to see it since I couldn't figure it out myself. Can someone help? We're basically using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_one_real_variable) definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t\mapsto\operatorname{Var}(X)_t$ is nondecreasing so it has left and right limits everywhere.

You can easily show with its definition that
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X)_{t+}-\operatorname{Var}(X)_t=\vert X_{t+}-X_t\vert,
$$
from which you trivially deduce that if $X$ is càd then so is $\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this property of montone functions. What does $\operatorname{Var}(X)_{t+}$ mean? Is it like $t+\varepsilon$? And "how trivial" is the last deduction?

Comment: I use the notation $Y_{t+}=\lim_{h\to0}Y_{t+\vert h\vert}$. And the last deduction is trivial because X càd implies $X_{t+}=X_t$ and therefore $\operatorname{Var}(X)_{t+}=\operatorname{Var}(X)_t$ according to the formula.